# Missing } inserted and extra } compile error together?

Tags: latex, pdflatex

I have a LaTeX project with the following line:

```
$$f\left(S_0e^{\left(r-\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2\right)T + \sigma \sqrt{T} x\right)},$$
```

Without this line, the compilation is ok. With it, there are two errors:

```
Missing } inserted. ...gma^2\right)T + \sigma \sqrt{T} x\right)}
```

and immediately after:

```
Extra }, or forgotten $. ...gma^2\right)T + \sigma \sqrt{T} x\right)}
```

both for the same, already mentioned line. It seams to me that the compiler inserts a '}' character, and then immediatelly after that it complains about that. Have you ever encountered such a problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your expression starts with a `(` followed by a `{`; it ends with a `)`, followed by a `}`.

So when the closing `)` is seen, a `}` is expected, and one is added, so everything balances.  But there is still that trailing `}`, which generates the second error (arguably caused by LaTeX itself).

Comment: Thanks, I missed that!